# Tuning nginx worker_process to obtain 100k hits per min

Tags: nginx

We have a server that is serving one html file.

Right now the server has 2 CPUs and 2GB of ram. From blitz.io, we are getting about 12k connections per minute and anywhere from 200 timeouts in that 60 seconds with 250 concurrent connections each second.

```
worker_processes  2;

events {
 worker_connections 1024;
}
```

If I increase the timeout, the response time starts creeping up beyond a second.

What else can I do to squeeze more juice out of this?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Config file:

```
worker_processes  4;  # 2 * Number of CPUs

events {
    worker_connections  19000;  # It's the key to high performance - have a lot of connections available
}

worker_rlimit_nofile    20000;  # Each connection needs a filehandle (or 2 if you are proxying)


# Total amount of users you can serve = worker_processes * worker_connections
```

more info: [Optimizing nginx for high traffic loads](https://web.archive.org/web/20180820022131/http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2011/04/optimizing-nginx-for-high-traffic-loads/)

Comment: I think the equation provided for total amount of users per sec is wrong. Instead the average amount of users served per second should be = worker_processes * worker_connections / (keepalive_timeout * 2) Therefore, the above conf file can server ~7.6K connections per sec, which is way above what @ablemike needs.  However, worker_rlimit_nofile is a good directive to use, if ulimit is restrictive and you don't want to modify it.

Comment: @Ethan, why it should be devided by 2? If every second we get 100 new connections, and timeout is 5, then strting with sixth second, we will constantly have 5*100 connections that is still not terminated on the server side. we may have less if some users are aborted connections himself

Comment: that formula does not work if keepalive is set to 0s (disabled)

Comment: thanks, Tilo. the better formula is:

total amount of users you can serve in 1 second = worker_processes*worker_connections/(keepalive_timeout+time_required_to_serve_one_request)

Comment: Each connection needs 2 file handles even for static files like images/JS/CSS. This is as 1 for the client's connection and the 2nd for opening the static file. Therefore, it's safer to change worker_rlimit_nofile = 2 * worker_connections.

Comment: Use worker_rlimit_nofile but one should also call 'ulimit -n' to set the open file count value per process. This is better done in the init script.

Comment: Thank you, Ethan. By our collective work, this topic becames encyclopedy of high-throughput nginxing :)

Comment: You should remove `keepalive_timeout` from your formula. Nginx closes keepalive connections when the `worker_connections` limit is reached.

Comment: Rather than removing it, you should decide on a minimum keepalive timeout you want to grant everyone to connect and use that instead in the formula.

Comment: How to determine worker_connections? We could not keep on increase it to meet our need, could we? It should be based on CPU, Memory, etc. Correct? Then how?

Comment: Adam, every worker_connection (in the sleeping state) needs 256 bytes of memory, so you can increase it easily