# nginx, uWSGI, 6K qps and the number of nginx workers times two cpu count?

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

I am referring to this post.

[Tuning nginx worker_process to obtain 100k hits per min](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325211/tuning-nginx-worker-process-to-obtain-100k-hits-per-min)

I have 3 8 core servers for a total of 24 cores.  Currently doing 6K qps.  In my nginx config I have one worker per core.  For uWSGI I am using the gevent loop and I have one process per core.  I set nice for nginx to -2 and nice for uWSGI to -1.

So..what is the better explanation for setting the number of workers to two times the number of cpu's?  I was always with the school of thought of one proccess per core.  I would love to increase if it will help.  Maybee number of cores plus half?  i.e 12?  I would love to get more juice out of my machines.  Latency is very critical.  I am a 100ms deadline to respond to a post.  So far working great.  Think time is 5ms but still....how can i better tune...

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 8;  
worker_priority -2;
worker_rlimit_nofile 200000;
events {
     worker_connections  30000;
     multi_accept on;
     use epoll;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official documentation recommends one worker per core (in common case):
http://nginx.org/r/worker_processes