# Python: uWSGI configuration for NGINX+FLASK

Tags: python, nginx, flask, wsgi, uwsgi

I successfully managed to install:
NGINX + uWSGI + Flask
on a CentOS 6.x server

but I still have some doubts in terms of configuration:

1) I am running NGINX as a service: service nginx start/stop/restart
if I type "ps aux | grep nginx", I can see 2 processes:
- (by user root) master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
- (by user nginx) worker process
is that OK?

2) I setup a virtualenv for Flask and installed the uWSGI package under such virtualenv.
Currenty I am starting the uWSGI manually by typing "uwsgi /somedir/uwsgi.ini", where uwsgi.ini is as follows:

```
chdir = /myappdir
uid = pyuser
chmod-socket = 666
socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
module = run
callable = app
virtualenv = /myappdir/myvirtualenv
```

Is it possible to start uWSGI as a service, similarly to NGINX (as described at point 1) ? Is such case should the user be root or non-root?

3) When I start the uWSGI, I am currently getting the following warning:

```
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
```

I realized that in the "uwsgi.ini" configuration file you can also configure a number of processes and threads. Considering the server I am running has just 1 core, can I set up multiple processes and threads? and if so, how many?

3b) On the NGINX configuration file "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" it is also possible to specify "worker_processes", which by default are 1. Can I increase that, or it can be higher than 1 only for multicore servers?

4) Beside the threads support disabled, when I start the uWSGI I also get these warnings. What do they mean?

```
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
```

Comment: I installed it in the virtualenv with "pip install uwsgi"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*I've moved the most important points from the comments.*

1. Yep, that's the normal behavior. Nginx's master process needs root
   privileges to manage listening sockets on the machine. [This](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,159000,159015#msg-159015)
   forum thread states that you **can** change it, but it may cause
   problems.  However, Nginx does allow to change the owner of the
   worker processes.
2. It depends on how the uWSGI was installed. If uWSGI was installed via `apt-get` you can start (stop, restart) it
   like this:

   `service uwsgi <action>`

   You installed uWSGI via `pip`, so the [daemonize](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#daemonize) option will do
   the trick:

   `/path/to/uwsgi --daemonize /path/to/logfile`

   You can start it under any user you want, BUT if you decide to run
   it under root, you should specify the [gid](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#gid) and
   [uid](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#uid) options.  uWSGI's [best practices page](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html) says:

   > Common sense: do not run uWSGI instances as root. You can start your
   >   uWSGIs as root, but be sure to drop privileges with the uid and gid
   >   options.

   Also take a look at [master-as-root](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html?highlight=uid#master-as-root) option.
3. You can create as many processes and threads as you want, but it should
   depend on how many requests you're trying to process (concurrent or
   per second). You can read about this [here](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html). I would try
   different configurations and choose which one works better.

   3b. Basically, `worker_processes` helps to handle concurrent
   requests. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325211/tuning-nginx-worker-process-to-obtain-100k-hits-per-min) question.
4. **WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process
   manager**

   You didn't specify a `master` option in your .ini file. While master
   process is certainly unnecessary, it is very useful. It helps to
   effectively control workers and respawn them when they die.

Comment: Thanks a lot Crystal! - 1) in the nginx.conf I set up the user as "nginx", but the master still runs as the root. Which option should I set? - 2) thanks a lot, I specified "deamonize" in the uwsgi.ini config file and it works - 3) I specified "enable-threads" and "processes = 2" in the uwsgi.ini, as I read as being a good compromise to set processes = 2*CPUs - 3b) I also set "worker_processes" to 2 in the nginx.conf - 4) are you sure it's needed? it's neither in uwsgi nor flask docs: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/uwsgi/

Comment: 1) I stopped nginx and started again, but the master process is still under the root user. 4) thanks, added master to the uwsgi.ini as well as I specified the pidfile, so that I can easily manage the uwsgi as described here: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Management.html#reloading-the-server

Comment: Thanks, you provided me a great help! As a beginner, I have now managed setup both NGINX and uWSGI successfully! I hope this post will help other people too!

Answer (score 1):

3b) When your nginx consumes a lot of CPU, you can use multi-core with `worker_process`.

Basically, Python application is much slower than nginx reverse proxy.  So one nginx process is enough.
But some nginx options (e.g. `gzip: on;` and `gzip_proxied: any`) consumes some CPU.
Watch top command output.  If nginx process consumes lot of CPU, you can increase worker_process.

When using nginx as reverse proxy, worker_process should <= number of CPU cores.