# Nginx WebSocket Reverse Proxy Limitations

Tags: nginx, proxy, websocket, jmeter, benchmarking

I've set up a Nginx Reverse Proxy that uses WebSocket connections and recently began benchmarking the setup with Apache JMeter. Whenever I would make over 600 requests, JMeter would return an  error for some of the requests. I individually tested each back-end web-server (with WebSockets) and no request errors appeared until around 11000 requests.

Is there a limit on the number of WebSocket connections Nginx allows or is there something which I have not setup correctly?

My /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file is set up as well follows:

```
location / 
{
    proxy_pass  http://backend;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
}
```

Comment: If there's any limitation, you'll probably find it in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady thanks I solved the problem with the information you gave me. For anyone needing info on the this here is the [link](http://wiki.nginx.org/EventsModule#worker_connections)

Answer (score 4):

If you want even more information about tweaking your nginx server you can get a short answer [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8217856/2149092) or the very longer detailed post [over here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180820022131/http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2011/04/optimizing-nginx-for-high-traffic-loads/)