# Calculate the maximum number of users at the same time on my server

Tags: nginx, server

I'm a developer who start in the server management. 
I would like to how I can calculate the maximum number of users I can have on my machine at the same time in function of his own configuration and of his web workers.

Here I'm on a OVH dedicated server with an Intel Xeon D-1520, 4 core at 2.2GHz and with 32GB of RAM. 
My web server is NGINX.

Is a formula exits or some websites who can calculate this number ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes You can calculate it based on your cpu and worker connections:
like this:
Config file:

`worker_processes  4;  # 2 * Number of CPUs
 events {
    worker_connections  19000;  # It's the key to high performance - have a lot of connections available
}
worker_rlimit_nofile    20000;  # Each connection needs a filehandle (or 2 if you are proxying)`

`# Total amount of users you can serve = worker_processes * worker_connections`

Reference: [Tuning nginx worker_process to obtain 100k hits per min](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325211/tuning-nginx-worker-process-to-obtain-100k-hits-per-min)

Comment: Sorry I'm late, Thank you very much, that was very useful :) 
A little tricky to understand the concept of workers but after a lot of readings about web workers it works ! :)